# How to composer install using a package's composer.lock file?

Tags: composer-php

If I have:

- a fresh project
- no `composer.lock`
- `composer.json` like the following

```
{
    "name": "fresh",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "consolidation/robo": "3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Then run `composer install`
It will install `consolidation/robo` and update the `consolidation/robo` internal dependencies instead of using the `consolidation/robo` internal `composer.lock` to get a known working version of the library.

How do to get `composer install` to use `https://github.com/consolidation/robo/blob/3.0.3/composer.lock` when installing `consolidation/robo` dependencies instead of running the equivalent of `composer update` on `consolidation/robo`?

Currently, it's retrieving a broken internal dependency and I have to outline it in my root composer.json which internal dependency should be retrieved. Where as the `https://github.com/consolidation/robo/blob/3.0.3/composer.lock` has the working version of the library.

Comment: There's no way you can use the composer.lock of any package for your own application - what would be the reason for doing this? "it's retrieving a broken internal dependency " - what does that mean?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that v3.0.3 of that package is already one year old - is there any reason for using an outdated version, and not the latest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way composer is **supposed** to work.

Lockfiles for dependencies are ignored, that's by design. If the package you are using has broken version constraints (e.g. it says its compatible with `^2.1` of `foo/bar`, but in reality was only tested with versions `>= 2.1.0 && <= 2.2.2`, and installing version 2.3 of `foo/bar` breaks), it's either becuse `foo/bar` broke the semver promise, or because the package you depend on was not adequately tested.

What you can do is simply add in your root `composer.json`:

```json
{
 "conflict":
     "foo/bar": ">=2.3"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunate that a first time install acts as a blind update. Thanks though.

Comment: It's the way it **has** to work, though. Lockfiles of dependencies couldn't be ever be taken into account. Packages could have compatible requiements, and yet incompatible lockfiles. E.g. one is compatible with `^2|^3` of a Foo, and its lockfile declares `^3` is installed. Another declares compatibility with Foo `^2`, so it using the lockfiles would block installation, whereas the actual version constraints actually would permit it though.